# store multiple values in maps

Tags: go, maps

**problem:** Store both an IP address as well as a time to a counter. something like this

ip, time, count

and then i would like to be able to increment the count for each ip:

ip++

in my map, and then on a given interval, i would like to iterate all keys and find the keys with a time stamp older than N minutes.

I need this to make sure i don't "forget" a key in memory if for some reason, client disconnect and i dont delete the key properly.

http://play.golang.org/p/RiWWOCARq7

**Question**: How do i add a time stamp to every IP address i store in my map. Also i need this be be used across multiple go routines

Im new to both programming and Golang, so if this is not even the correct approach, if anyone could point me in the right direction, i would appreciate it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type IPCounter struct {
    IPAddr string
    Time   time.Time
    Count  int
}

type ipCounterMap struct {
    counters map[string]IPCounter
    mutex    sync.RWMutex
}

var ipCounters = ipCounterMap{counters: make(map[string]IPCounter)}

// Get IP address counter
func Counter(ipAddr string) IPCounter {
    ipCounters.mutex.RLock()
    defer ipCounters.mutex.RUnlock()
    counter, found := ipCounters.counters[ipAddr]
    if !found {
        counter.IPAddr = ipAddr
    }
    return counter
}

// Increment IP address counter
func Incr(ipAddr string) {
    now := time.Now().UTC()
    ipCounters.mutex.Lock()
    defer ipCounters.mutex.Unlock()
    counter, found := ipCounters.counters[ipAddr]
    if !found {
        counter.IPAddr = ipAddr
    }
    counter.Time = now
    counter.Count++
    ipCounters.counters[ipAddr] = counter
}

// Delete IP address counter
func Delete(ipAddr string) {
    ipCounters.mutex.Lock()
    defer ipCounters.mutex.Unlock()
    delete(ipCounters.counters, ipAddr)
}

// Get old IP address counters old durations ago
func OldIPCounters(old time.Duration) []IPCounter {
    var counters []IPCounter
    oldTime := time.Now().UTC().Add(-old)
    ipCounters.mutex.RLock()
    defer ipCounters.mutex.RUnlock()
    for _, counter := range ipCounters.counters {
        if counter.Time.Before(oldTime) {
            counters = append(counters, counter)
        }
    }
    return counters
}

func main() {}
```

Comment: Works also. I like this one, since its very complete. i will play around with this one

Comment: @OneOfOne , i hope thats a good thing? :-) because i used this soloution.. so far it works fine.

Comment: Yeah it's great code, I was just commenting on the style.

Answer (score 5):

You probably want a map of ip -> struct { ip, counter, lastTime }
that way, you can look up the counter by ip and then update it

```
var Counters = map[string]*Counter{}

type Counter struct {
    ip       string
    count    int
    lastTime time.Time
}
```

Here's a working example on Play http://play.golang.org/p/TlCTc_4iq5

Adding the find older than is simply range over the values of the map comparing to now and do something when it's old enough.

Comment: "i need this be be used across multiple go routines." Your solution won't work for that.

Comment: updated for concurrency (still not safe on counter, but that probably doesn't matter in this specific case)

Comment: Works for me. lacked safety, fixed now. ill vote it as soon as i can (apparently i need repuation 15), ill do it later.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need a [struct](http://www.golang-book.com/9/index.htm). A [map](http://www.golang-book.com/6/index.htm) is for storing a collection where all the keys are of one type and all the elements are of another (or the same type).

For grouping a collection of variables of different data types, that are related, use a `struct`

e.g.

```
type IPCounter struct {
    ip    string
    time  time.Time
    count int
}
```

Here's some sample code that creates one of these objects and increments the count:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type IPAddressCounter struct {
    ip    string
    time  time.Time
    count int
}

func (i *IPAddressCounter) IncrementCount() {
    i.count++
}

func makeCounter(ip string) IPAddressCounter {
    return IPAddressCounter{
        ip:   ip,
        time: time.Now(),
    }
}

func main() {
    mapOfIPCounters := make(map[string]IPAddressCounter)

    mapOfIPCounters["192.168.1.1"] = makeCounter("192.168.1.1")
    mapOfIPCounters["192.168.1.2"] = makeCounter("192.168.1.2")
    mapOfIPCounters["192.168.1.3"] = makeCounter("192.168.1.3")

    for key, value := range mapOfIPCounters {
        value.IncrementCount()
        mapOfIPCounters[key] = value

        fmt.Println("The counter for "+key+" is", mapOfIPCounters[key].count)
    }

}
```

Comment: The question says they have a collection of structs used across multiple goroutines.

Comment: The word 'strut' doesn't appear in the question. I've just taken some of my own free time to help this guy and you downvote? Thanks.

Comment: The answer is wrong. It solvees the wrong problem. It won't work.

Comment: Where does it say that in the question?

Comment: "How do i add a time stamp to every IP address i store in my map", you use a struct instead of a plain string. How is that wrong?

Comment: Your map solution can't be used across multiple goroutines.

Comment: Could you explain why that is? I would appreciate knowing where I've gone wrong, so it doesn't happen again.

Comment: @MattHarrison you would want to use channels to work with sharing memory. Something like this https://gobyexample.com/stateful-goroutines would allow your solution to work across multiple goroutines.

Comment: @Joe sure, I realise that. But there's nothing fundamentally wrong with the data structures I have chosen?

Comment: @MattHarrison the data structure isn't the issue, but the question is referring to accessing from multiple goroutines. Not having something like a channel or mutex in your solution is only answering 1/2 of the question IMO. See peterSO's answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It wasn't mentioned how the map needs to be thread safe. I assumed each go routine will only access 1 index of the map each and would thus be ok to be used across multiple goroutines without the use of the mutexes/locks.

Comment: BUG ALERT: A bug has been reported for the map example. The map is not updated. Bug: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/k4rE6LqMENY/fA-B2NRUVxYJ Example: http://play.golang.org/p/T9zyicTrMK

Comment: @MattHarrison: Go maps are implemented as hash maps. The map is dynamically reorganized to accomodate insertions and deletions. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table